# Split string beside a separator

Tags: python, regex

The title may seem a bit weird but here;s an example of input and output

```
'425557: Slime Poudrin 425564: Slime Poudrin 425566: Slime Poudrin 425590: Slime Poudrin'
```

Should become

```
['425557: Slime Poudrin', '425564: Slime Poudrin', '425566: Slime Poudrin', '425590: Slime Poudrin']
```

unfortunately the ids can range from 100000 to 500000 so I cant split by the number, and it needs to be preserved in the output. I'm assuming I could split 6 characters to the left of ':' but I have no idea how to do it or search for a solution. Alternatively if there's any way to take multi line text split by Enter that works too but the solutions I've found for that seem to require you enter text line by line anyway. which doesn't work for hundreds of lines of text.
I assume there's a method with regex splitting but I don't quite understand it.

Comment: also to clarify there are other names that can be next to the numbers. which could be anything, including URLs

Comment: Find out what the format is and use a proper parser for that format.

Answer (score 4):

you can use regex to split your text

```
import re

text = '425557: Slime Poudrin 425564: Slime Poudrin 425566: Slime Poudrin 425590: Slime Poudrin'

splited = re.findall("\d*\:[^\d]*", text)

print(splited)
```

output:

```
['425557: Slime Poudrin ', '425564: Slime Poudrin ', '425566: Slime Poudrin ', '425590: Slime Poudrin']
```

Comment: This almost entirely worked! thank you! however,
"417766: Ysage [Ver. 2Y2D]'s scalp"
gets split like
'417766: Ysage [Ver. '

Comment: ah, more specifically, it seems like any entry containing numbers followed by a special character gets broken. is there any way the regex expression could be specified to 6 numbers and a colon as opposed to any amount of numbers and any special character?

Comment: ```splited = re.findall("([\d]{6}\:(\d{0,5}[^\d]+)*)", text)```
this is works for me

Answer (score 1):

You can split by the first occurrence of a digit. Then strip the whitespace at the end.

```
import re
test_str = '425557: Slime Poudrin 425564: Slime Poudrin 425566: Slime Poudrin 425590: Slime Poudrin'
## splits your string by first occurrence of any digit 0-9
split_text = re.findall('\d*\D+',test_str)
final_split_text = [words.strip() for words in split_text]
```

Output:

```
['425557: Slime Poudrin', '425564: Slime Poudrin', '425566: Slime Poudrin', '425590: Slime Poudrin']
```

Answer (score 1):

A more complex regex with a negative lookahead to stop at the next "\d+:" sequence will allow interim digits in the string (but not digits plus colon). Since the negative lookahead only works for a single current character, its wrapped in a non-capture group with 1 or more matches.

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "425557: Slime Poudrin 425564: Slime Poudrin 425566: Slime Poudrin 425590: Slime Poudrin 417766: Ysage [Ver. 2Y2D]'s scalp 425566: Slime Poudrin"
>>> re.findall(r"(\d+: (?:.(?!\d+:))+)", text2)
['425557: Slime Poudrin', '425564: Slime Poudrin', '425566: Slime Poudrin', '425590: Slime Poudrin', "417766: Ysage [Ver. 2Y2D]'s scalp", '425566: Slime Poudrin']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split`:

```
import re

s = '425557: Slime Poudrin 425564: Slime Poudrin 425566: Slime Poudrin 425590: Slime Poudrin'

rgx = r' +(?=\d{6}: )'
print re.split(rgx, s)
```

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/YBJVxB/1/) | [Python code](http://tpcg.io/M4J6SOSG)

The regular expression reads, "match one or more spaces followed by six digits followed by a colon". `(?=\d{6}: )` is a *positive lookahead*.